# SASS - compare vh and px with min function

Tags: sass

I am trying to get the minimum between 7.6% of the viewport height and 55px.

```
min-height: min(7.6vh, 55px);
```

This gives me an error about incompatible units. Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SASS compiler can't know the viewport height of the target device(s), so it is impossible to compare vh to a fixed value given pixels.

What you can do is to set the height to either of the two numbers and set a min-height to the other number. However, the semantics are slightly different, as you now also have a max-height. In the following example, the div will take (at most) 100% of the viewport height, but at least 450px:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background: darkgreen;
  height: 450px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The Sass `min()` function only works when both values have the same unit (`%`, `px`, `em`, etc.). However, CSS itself has a [`min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) function built in. Modern Dart Sass will automatically use the CSS function when possible.

For older versions of Sass, to use the CSS function you need to override `min()` with your own custom function like this:

```scss
// Override Sass min()
@function min($numbers...) {
  @return m#{i}n(#{$numbers});
}

div {
  // This now works
  width: min(7.6vh, 55px);
}
```

Thanks to [Jianqiu Xiao on GitHub](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2378#issuecomment-433868712) for pointing out the "override" solution.

Comment: To override Sass max(), see implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535307/sass-create-function-to-do-max-and-min-on-margin)

Comment: You can escape min and max by putting a backslash \ in front of it. e.g., \min(...) or \max(...)