# SASS create function to do max and min on margin

Tags: sass

I couldn't find a solution for this problem: I need to set a margin in SASS with a max between 2 values, one is a `calc()` and the other is a regular px value. It would be something like this:

```
$calculation: calc(15vw + 10px);

.cssClass {
    margin-right: max($calculation, 100px);
}
```

Any ideas on how to create a SCSS function or some way to make this work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS - compare vh and px with min function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195391/sass-compare-vh-and-px-with-min-function)

Comment: You question should be answered in the duplicate post.

Comment: Sorry but it's not the same bc what I need is a margin not a width so I cannot use a `min-margin` because that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sass `max()` function doesn't work with values that have different units.

That said, you can use the CSS [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) function by overriding the Sass version with your own:

```scss
// Override Sass function
@function max($numbers...) {
  @return m#{a}x(#{$numbers});
}

$calculation: calc(15vw + 10px);

.cssClass {
  margin-right: max($calculation, 100px);
}
```

...the SCSS above compiles to this CSS:

```css
.cssClass {
  margin-right: max(calc(15vw + 10px), 100px);
}
```

Credit to [Jianqiu Xiao on GitHub](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2378#issuecomment-433868712) for pointing out this solution. Having to create a custom function is an unfortunate Sass compiler quirk, though it has apparently been fixed in Dart Sass already.